# Java why does HashSet's remove() take O(1) time, when ArrayList's remove() takes O(n)?

Tags: java, runtime

I found out that the remove(Object o) of Java's HashSet take O(1) constant time, whereas the remove(Object o) operation of ArrayList take O(N) where N is the size of ArrayList.

Could anyone please explain, in detail, why that is?

Comment: Do you know what a HashSet is and how it stores and retrieves data?

Answer (score 9):

`HashSet`'s `remove()` takes `O(1)` expected time to locate the element to be removed - the `hashCode()` takes you to the bin that contains the element, and each bin is expected to have a small number of entries, so finding the element in the bin and removing it should take constant time.

On the other hand, in an `ArrayList` you have to iterate over all the elements until you find the element you wish to remove - that takes `O(n)`. Even after you locate the element, the removal itself involves moving all the elements that had a higher index than the removed element - that also takes `O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

**ArrayList :-**

An ArrayList in Java is a List that is backed by an array.

On operation remove(i) arraylist removes the element at the specified position in the list , shifts any subsequent elements to the left.

So in worst case scenario if you remove the first element, it needs to shift the remaining n-1 elements to the left . Hence the complexity is o(n).

**HashSet:-**

Java internally uses hashmap to store the elements of set. The elements of hashset are key in the hashmap and the value is some dummy object.

The remove operation in hashmap works as :-

1. Find the hash value of the key.
2. Find the index for the key in entry table.
3. Iterate over the bucket to find the key.
4. Remove the key from the bucket link list.

In the worst case scenario, a bucket can contain all the key and the complexity seems to be o(n). But in real life any dependable hash map implementation, coupled with a half decent hash function, has a retrieval performance of O(1) with a very small factor (2, in fact) in the expected case, within a very narrow margin of variance.

Comment: From my understanding, HashSet does not retain the order of its elements, therefore there are no indexes. Am I wrong?
If there are no indexes, why would the remove operation find the index for the key in entry table?

Comment: Yes as i mentioned hashset internally uses hashmap. Hashmap stores a particular key at a particular position in the table. The entry in this table is not the same as that of insertion.You can get a better idea about hashmap from this [link](http://www.thejavageek.com/2016/03/18/working-of-hashmap-put-method/)